# Backup Postgres Database to Azure Blob storage using Airflow DAG

Tags: database, postgresql, backup, airflow, azure-blob-storage

I am currently working on Postgressql database and have to create a database backup on a daily basis using Airflow DAG.
I have created a DAG and I am able to create the backup using BashOperator and pg_dump command. But this approach reveals the sensitive information in Airflow logs.

Is there an option we can mask the passwords and secret key?
Or Can we use PostgresOperator or Postgreshook to create the backup?